# What does Lexmark mean by 25W universal power supply?

Tags: power-supply, printer, power, lexmark-printer

I have a [Lexmark x5650 printer/scanner combo](http://www.lexmark.com/US/en/view/product%3A4428/Lexmark+X5650/catId=product%3A4428-category&prodId=4428-product) but I lost the power supply when moving.

Lexmark's site says the following regarding the power supply:

> **Power Supply**
>
> 25 Watt Universal Power Supply (100 - 240V AC, 50/60 Hz)

I'm trying to find the correct replacement online, but my searches are taking me to [Ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/GENUINE-Delta-Power-Supply-Adapter-ADP-12UB-for-Lexmark-Dell-Printers-TESTED-/112069085655?hash=item1a17d689d7:g:EzcAAOxydINSXFUE) or [other sites](http://shop.lexmark.com/wpo-catalog/US_e/search/data_type:part/40X5781) neither of which specifically mention my printer.

**What does Lexmark mean by "Universal Power Supply"?** Is that an industry-standard size, wattage, voltage, etc? Or is it just universal to their manufactured printers? Are there any sure-fire ways to get the power supply I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Universal Power Supply" simply means that the power supply will work on any mains system, from 100 to 240 V and 50 or 60 Hz. In essence, the adapter will work on the mains power of any country.

The output voltage of the supply isn't specified. It's best to call Lexmark customer service at 1 (800) LEXMARK (539-6275) (I'm assuming you're in the US, judging from your links) to see if they can sell you one.

The Epson and HP printers I've worked with more recently (mostly business-class inkjets) plug straight into the wall using an industry-standard ([IEC C7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320#C7.2FC8_coupler)) cable and do not require an external power adapter of any sort.

Comment: This does require a special "block" that plugins in to the printer, so it's a bummer it has to be the specific one. But thanks for the explanation! (and excellent deduction regarding my locale)